# Hide product field in gravity form

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am trying to hide the product field in my gravity form as I am displaying the price from woocommerce. How can I hide this field?I tried using gravity form styler but I am not able to achieve the same.Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the "gf_hidden" class to your field via the Field Setting's "CSS Class Name" setting - or - you can set your product field type to be "Hidden" via the "Field Type" setting.